# Plugin Route registration issue in nopcommerce

Tags: nopcommerce

At this moment, I am register at AreaRegistraion as below:-

```
public class AdminAreaRegistration : AreaRegistration
    {
        public override string AreaName
        {
            get { return "Admin"; }
        }

        public override void RegisterArea(AreaRegistrationContext context)
        {

                    context.MapRoute(
                        "custom_admin_order",
                        "Admin/Order/List/",
                        new { controller = "CustomOrder", action = "List", area = "Admin", id = "" },
                        new[] { "Misc.CustomAdminOrder.Controllers" });

        }
    }
```

It is working, but sometime doesn't work and need to restart the application and clear cache several times to make it work.

So right now I need a better way to make it 100% work.

Comment: I guess it is a plugin. Every time you make a change in plugin, you need to rebuild the solution.

Comment: @batmaci, just enough to rebuild plugin ;)

Comment: @Dmitry of course. just a habit of mine to rebuild the whole solution to feel secure. it doesnt hurt or take much time though :)

Comment: @batmaci I do day 20-30 rebuilds nopCommerce. Is a long time :)))

Comment: You should not re-register the Admin area